# how to fit B spline curve on Gray image using three points

Tags: image, transformation, curve-fitting, bspline

I have a gray scale image.

I need to fit a curve using three points. I have attached the paper (Yellow arc), which was published in PLoS One, [here](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0190348)

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325809836_Automatic_outer_and_inner_breast_tissue_segmentation_using_multi-parametric_MRI_images_of_breast_tumor_patients

Answer (score 2):

This paper is about the analysis of landmarks on established images. The B-spline technique is about breaking and refitting a curve across data points: there are numerous approaches in R to do this, but it is not clear whether this will solve your "undefined" grey scale image.

I would send this back to your supervisor and ask for a better definition of the question, rather than say "problem X", "paper Y". Wno knows if this is a fit to your problem, but normally in landmark analysis the starting point is to calcualate the distance between landmarks and trigonometry to provide further initial characterisation. The ratios between landmarks across a large data set provide the material for multi-variate analysis following a data transformation (often procrustes transformation to remove the scaling dimension in landmark analysis).

In summary, the entire background to landmark analysis appears absent from your question, curve fitting over a non-transformed data set - i.e. size variation is present - is questionable in context and in summary this represents questionable research supervision.

Comment: Thanks for your comments